# Proper Configuration of Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get custom dimensions working in Google Analytics and I'm having trouble getting them to show up. My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('set', {
          'dimension1': 'users-email-address@xyz.com',
          'dimension2': 'users-id'
        });

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'xxxxxxxxxx.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `set` after `create`? Also, install a browser plugin such as Omnibug for Firefox or GA Debug for Chrome and you will be able to confirm the request is being sent.

Comment: Where do you expect them to show up (as for now they won't appear in standard reports, but you can use them in segments and custom reports) ?

Comment: could it be that I am trying to capture an email address and GA is not allowing that and barfing?

Comment: No - that kind of data is not allowed but Google will capture it nonetheless. Have you set up your custom dimensions in the admin section of your ga account ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom dims/mets are sent to Google Analytics with hits, so you need to make sure that after setting them, a hit is sent. Which means in this case, the 'set' should come after the create and before the send.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'xxxxxxxxxx.com');
ga('set', {
          'dimension1': 'some value',
          'dimension2': 'some other value'
        });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is all covered and explained pretty well in [Custom Dimensions & Metrics - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)

Also, you should not be sending personally identifiable information such as an email address to Google Analytics. See the [policy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy).

Comment: this is what did it. figured this out on my own but forgot to come back here. thanks.